mix a geometry nodes setup with rig
I'm currently rigging a griffon and I'm working on the wings. For the base I modelled a mesh where I scattered several feathers via "distribute points on faces" and "instances on point node". the base itself is bound to a rig (fk and ik shoulder, elbow, wrist, typical setup)
Now when I move the basemesh with the rig, the instances follow the location but they won't change their rotation. I tried using the normal value of my base mesh to give this information to the instances. I also used the capture attribute node, didn't work.




Why are you adding 2,0,0 to the normal? That will certainly spoil things and create unpredictable rotations.
The best way to approach this is:

Instead of taking the normal from the point distribution, take the rotation
Connect this rotation straight to the "instance on points"

(If you need) Use a "Rotate Rotation" node in between to add a constant rotation to the point rotation (if your original object is in the correct position with rotation applied, it won't be necessary)



